PG: How to release disk space after truncating string columns
select version()
PostgreSQL 15.3 (Ubuntu 20.04) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 64-bit

We have an application that stores big jsons in result TEXTFIELD.
Data inside this column looks like this:
{"data": "[.....]", "metadata": {....}}

Sometimes the data is more than 100 MB.
So recently we faced a problem: there is no more free disk space. Our zabbix indicates
Space on /var/lib/postgresql (pused) % = 94.74

directory size is 550 GB.
So we decided to archive old rows into s3 and truncate the data. According to my calculations I truncated about 50 GB of data and now the result column of these rows looks like this:
{"data": "", "metadata": {....}}

After that we launched autovacuum. But this step did not meet with success: zabbix indicates that we haven't freed up the disk space.
Space on /var/lib/postgresql (pused) % = 94.70

What can i do to free the space on /var/lib/postgresql ?
